# automate electron based desktop app using testcafe not working

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

i am trying to automate tests for 'lens' electron based desktop application.i was following this link [enter link description here](http://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-electron#testing-an-executable-electron-application) to setup the test for electron app.This link expects a 'mainwindowurl' but application doesn't have any main page, but testcafe give suggestion of the mainwindowurl as an error so tried it works but am not convinced with the suggrstion urls ,but same way want to give fixture page url on the test what should be the url should i need to give? then have got one more error ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.Please can you guys suggest what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Each and every Electron application has to navigate to a page after opening a window.
I guess that the mentioned Lens app is an Kubernetes IDE: https://github.com/lensapp/lens.

This app uses the `BrowserWindow.loadURL` function to navigate to the main page:
https://github.com/lensapp/lens/blob/a61425124f18b1cc2d8a507084a472029acc3e6b/src/main/window-manager.ts#L101.

Digging the code a bit more, I found that the main window URL is just `localhost` with some port:
https://github.com/lensapp/lens/blob/a61425124f18b1cc2d8a507084a472029acc3e6b/src/main/window-manager.ts#L33.

I guess it is possible to determine or set the port number by looking at the code a bit more or asking Lens developers about it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have used the splash html as my mainwindowurl , because other url has dynamic port , i may have to check how to get the proxyport number. But after giving splash.html as mainwindowurl testcafe and electron open's the lens application, but it run for a while and it returns the following error "ERROR The Electron 9.4.0 / macOS 10.15.7 browser disconnected. This problem may appear when a browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues." would like understand what is stopping to execute the testcase.

Comment: Hello,

This information is not sufficient to reproduce this issue. Please create a [bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) with a minimal reproducible example in the TestCafe repository.

Comment: @Andrey Belym, as you suggest i have found the port number and form a URL like 'http://localhost:<portnumber>', Now i got an error "The page URL is expected to be a string, but it was object." what is it?

Comment: It looks like you passed an object where a string is expected. Please check this. If this does not help, create a [bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) with a simple reproducible example in the TestCafe repository.